# SwitchCompat state change when back button is pressed

Tags: java, android, toggle, sharedpreferences, back-button

i have a SwitchCompat widget in the ActionBar.

When back button is pressed, and "reopen" the app, SwitchCompat loses the state, goes from on to off.

I am implementing a foreground, but this does not prevent the SwitchCompat changes state.

I tried with SharedPreferences but app crash.

MainActivity.java

```
SwitchCompat switchService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

switchService = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

    LoadPreferences();
}

private void SavePreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("state", switchService.isEnabled());
    editor.apply();   // I missed to save the data to preference here,.
}

private void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean  state = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("state", false);
    switchService.setEnabled(state);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    SavePreferences();
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.toggle_ButtonL);
    MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item).findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    switchService = (SwitchCompat) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    switchService.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                // Creates SMSMonitorService intent
                Intent SMSMonitorIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SMSMonitorService.class);
                // Start SMSMonitorService
                startService(SMSMonitorIntent);
                Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "SMSMonitor Started");

            } else {
                // Creates SMSMonitorService intent
                Intent SMSMonitorIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SMSMonitorService.class);
                // Stop SMSMonitorService
                stopService(SMSMonitorIntent);
                Log.i(DEBUG_TAG,"SMSMonitor Stopped");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.toggle_off), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Logcat:

```
01-25 23:41:07.995    1341-1341/com.test.wikitext E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.test.wikitext, PID: 1341
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.wikitext/com.test.wikitext.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.test.wikitext.MainActivity.LoadPreferences(MainActivity.java:249)
        at com.test.wikitext.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)    
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
```

(continue)

How i can save the state of SwitchCompat that when back button is pressed this no loses their present state?

Answer (score 1):

I know i was late to the party , but this might help others

Hi as like you i've been searching answer for this the answer is in your question just replace the code like the following

In OnCreateOptionsMenu change the code from

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.toggle_ButtonL);
MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item).findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
switchService = (SwitchCompat) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
```

to

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.toggle_ButtonL);
 switchService = (SwitchCompat)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item).findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
```

this will do the trick. now we can get rid of that NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

You must remove

```
switchService = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

LoadPreferences();
```

from `onCreate` method because the `SwitchCompat` is not in your layout and it is on the actionBar. then call `LoadPreferences();` after

```
 switchService = (SwitchCompat) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
```

Comment: Thanks but if i do that, in SavePreferences and LoadPreferences methods, "switchService" is not find.

Comment: Any suggestion please?